# AngularJS + Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Привет.

Не подскажите, как можно перекомпилировать страницу после того, как TurboLinks(Ajax) ее загрузил?

Я хочу использовать Angular + Turbolinks, но сейчас вот, проблема в том, что при загрузки страницы - она отдается как есть, ng-controller Turbolinks конечно заменяет, но эффекта ноль. А так же в консоль вбрасывается ошибка:

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

Не подскажите, как я могу решить эти две проблемки?

Нашел несколько полуживых вопросов на английском StackOverflow, но, решения для этих проблем там не нашел.

Пример кода:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="App" ng-controller="MainController">
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Всё. Больше ничего нет. На второй странице, абсолютно тоже самое, в контроллерах нет ничего кроме переменной `$scope.title`.

Ещё раз повторю суть проблемы:

1. Нажимаю на ссылку, Turbolink подгружает контент с другой страницы,
   заменяя текущий body.
2. У текущего body контроллер теперь не MainController, а
   TestController.
3. Новый контроллер не инициализируется.

---

Что такое Turbolinks? https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Comment: нужен [mcve] иначе непонятно что и как ты пытаешься делать

Comment: @Grundy

Две обычные html страницы, у каждой свой контроллер.


И у каждой одна единственная переменная:
$scope.title = '...';

И все.

Comment: Просто, при загрузки Аяксом другой страницы, контроллер  не инициализируется. Я не знаю как это пофиксить.

Comment: Понятнее не стало: приведи пример кода. В идеале - пример который можно запустить и посмотреть в чем проблема. Все необходимое должно быть в вопросе. Для редактирования вопроса используй кнопку [edit] под ним

Comment: @Grundy Я не смог в Codepen, поэтому, описал тут более подробно.

Comment: Можешь попробовать сделать на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) там можно создавать несколько страниц. Добавь описание/ссылку что такое _Turbolink_. Ангуляр сам умеет подгружать шаблоны, для этого ему не нужны дополнительные инструменты. Кроме этого, в шаблонах не нужны теги html/body - попробуй их убрать совсем

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55260/discussion-between-grundy-and-sasha-t).